# How do we call a class method from another class method?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

what is the correct way calling a class method from another class method?

is it

```
  className methodName
```

or

```
   self methodName
```

or

```
    className class methodName
```

can we use self when we don't create an instance of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `self methodName` if you are calling it from the same class. In Smalltalk class is an object itself, so `self methodName` in a class method sends message to self i.e. class object.

This is good also to maintain consistency during inheritance. Imagine that you have `SuperClass` and `SubClass`. Then if you use `self methodName` somewhere in `SuperClass`, then in `SubClass` it will be equivalent to `SubClass methodName` because the object executing the method will be `SubClass` object. Now if you hardcode `SuperClass methodName` then it will be the same in subclasses, and this is probably not what you are expecting.

If you will do `className class methodName` you will send a message to `className class` object, which is an instance of `Metaclass`, an this is probably completely different from what you expect.

Here is a picture showing the core concept of Smalltalk hierarchy. (hollow arrows are inheritance).

[image: Smalltalk class hierarchy]

### Long story short:

If you have

```
SomeClass class >> #someMethod
    "do something"
```

Then you should use

```
SomeClass class >> #otherMethod
    self someMethod
```

or

```
OtherClass class >> #otherMethod
    SomeClass someMethod
```

Second will work for first case, but out of design point of view first is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

Using `self` is considered better because you avoid duplicating the class name everywhere. As far as whether the other ones work, try and let us know ;) It would be more effective to compile and run a one line method in your image than to ask on SO!! Exploration and experimentation are part of what Smalltalk is all about - use the force, Luke :)

Comment: It is, the difference is that Java doesn't have the dual class hierarchy that allows the existence of class side methods.

"self" is always the current instance - but in a class method "the current instance" is the Class itself, not a particular instance of the class.  "this" in Java is also always the current instance, but the different object model means that there's no scenario where "the current instance" is the Class.